# Overhead when calling a component function vs inline code - ColdFusion

Tags: performance, coldfusion, jvm, components, overhead

I've been diagnosing a performance issue with generating a CSV containing around 50,000 lines and I've narrowed it down to a single function that is used once per line.

After a lot of messing about, I've discovered that there is an overhead in using the function, rather than placing the logic directly in the loop - my question is: Why?!

The function in question is very simple, it accepts a string argument and passes that to a switch/case block containing around 15 options - returning the resulting string.
I've put a bunch of timers all over the place and discovered that a lot (not all) of the time this function call takes between 0 and 200 ms to run... however if I put the exact same code inline, it sits at 0 on every iteration.

All this points to a fundamental issue in my understanding of object instantiation and I'd appreciate some clarification.

I was always under the impression that if I instantiate a component at the top of a page, or indeed if I instantiate it in a persistent scope like Application or Session, then it would be placed into memory and subsequent calls to functions within that component would be lightning fast. 
It seems however, that there is an overhead to calling these functions and while we're only talking a few milliseconds, when you have to do that 50,000 times it quickly adds up.

Furthermore, it seems that doing this consumes resources. I'm not particularly well versed in the way the JVM uses memory, I've read up on it and played with settings and such, but it's an overwhelming topic - especially for those of us with no Java development experience. It seems that when calling the method over inline code, sometimes the ColdFusion service just collapses and the request never ends. Other times it does indeed complete, although way too slowly. This suggests that the request can complete only when the server has the resources to handle it - and thus that the method call itself is consuming memory... (?)

If indeed the calling of a method has an overhead attached, I have a big problem. It's not really feasible to move all of this code inline, (while the function in question is simple, there are plenty of other functions that I will need to make use of) and doing so goes against everything I believe as a developer!!

So, any help would be appreciated.

Just for clarity and because I'm sure someone will ask for it, here's the code in question:

**EDIT:** As suggested, I've changed the code to use a struct lookup rather than CFSwitch - below is amended code for reference, however there's also a test app in pastebin links at the bottom.

**Inside the init method:**

```
    <cfset  Variables.VehicleCategories = {
            'T1'    : 'Beetle'
        ,   'T1C'   : 'Beetle Cabrio'
        ,   'T2'    : 'Type 2 Split'
        ,   'T2B'   : 'Type 2 Bay'
        ,   'T25'   : 'Type 25'
        ,   'Ghia'  : 'Karmann Ghia'
        ,   'T3'    : 'Type 3'
        ,   'G1'    : 'MK1 Golf'
        ,   'G1C'   : 'MK1 Golf Cabriolet'
        ,   'CADDY' : 'MK1 Caddy'
        ,   'G2'    : 'MK2 Golf'
        ,   'SC1'   : 'MK1/2 Scirocco'
        ,   'T4'    : 'T4'
        ,   'CO'    : 'Corrado'
        ,   'MISC'  : 'MISC'
    } />
```

**Function being called:**

```
<cffunction name="getCategory" returntype="string" output="false">
    <cfargument name="vehicleID" required="true" type="string" hint="Vehicle type" />

    <cfscript>
        if (structKeyExists(Variables.VehicleCategories, Arguments.VehicleID)) {
            return Variables.VehicleCategories[Arguments.VehicleID];
        }
        else {
            return 'Base SKUs';
        }
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

As requested, I've created a test application to replicate this issue:

http://pastebin.com/KE2kUwEf - Application.cfc

http://pastebin.com/X8ZjL7D7 - TestCom.cfc (Place in 'com' folder outside webroot)

http://pastebin.com/n8hBLrfd - index.cfm

Comment: Not sure what's up, but first thing I would do is change the switch to a struct lookup. [Quick example](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1785f7bc2ed25a4f6edb).

Comment: Oh, make sure you have `output=false` on the cfcomponent and cffunction tags! That will add overhead that could slow it down.

Comment: As Peter mentioned, add the `output=false` and try again. I think that will help.

Comment: Alas, `output=false` doesn't seem to have made any difference - shame, I thought that sounded like it might do it!
As for changing to a struct lookup, it might be a little quicker but I'm more concerned with the overhead of the function call than the code itself - if I put it inline in the .cfm page, it's exponentially quicker. My concern is the other functions I'm using are not so easily dealt with.

Comment: why not create a struct on the page and reference it that way? I don't think a function is the best way to handle this.

Comment: Maybe not, but I'm afraid that's not my question - I can't see why the same code works much faster inline, than it does in a function. There may be better ways of achieving this particular goal, but I'd like to understand why the function call has an overhead attached.

Comment: A function doesn't add meaningful overhead - that's the general consensus (and ideal situation). If you're asserting otherwise (and want help figuring out why) then you need code that demonstrates this - i.e. not the function you're calling, but in-context code that calls it - ideally simplified into a form that others can run (without dependencies) and see the same issue.

Comment: Also the precise CF and JVM versions might be relevant, so that info should be provided.

Comment: Where does this function live?  On the page calling it?  In a .cfm file that gets cfincluded?  In a cfc?  If it's in a cfc, try the other two methods and see if the behaviour changes.

Comment: That's what I thought, yes... but all my testing indicates an overhead. I'll see if I can knock up a reproducible test.

Comment: CF passes simple objects by value and not by reference. Every time you call the function two new values are created in memory for Arguments.VehicleID and Local.Category. Your slowdown may be due to garbage collection of the newly created variables once the function completes. When you run the same code in line, I'm assuming your assigning new values to existing variables, or just switching on the values out of the CSV file, which wouldn't use any additional memory.

Comment: This is the kind of thing I was thinking, but I'm not entirely sure I understand. I think I would expect the object to be by reference, I'm not sure I see _why_ it would be by value - but I think that would explain the issue. What would be the distinction that CF would use to decide if an object should be reference or value, and why? Any way I can force the issue?

Comment: If Arguments.VehicleID is the same on multiple calls to the function, wouldn't it reuse those?

Comment: I'm unsure how CF optimizes function calls. I would assume it wouldn't reuse argument variable references for you can manipulate the data in the argument scope. One thing you could try is rewrite / clone the function were it takes a struct. Structs are passed by reference and wouldn't take any additional memory with in the function.

Comment: In the debugging output, it aggregates calls to the function by grouping those with identical arguments - so I figure it must be able to make that distinction under the hood.

In any case, I still don't think I understand the problem - if the code exists inline, it still has to do the same amount of processing, be it a switch or struct notation. I don't really understand why a function call doing the same work would cause the overhead. The Local.Category value changes on every iteration regardless of where the logic is. Inline there's no Arguments.VehicleID, but wouldn't that just be double?

Comment: Not read all the latest comments, but a quick note: **if you've got "Report Execution Times" enabled in debug settings, turn it off** - that can give false slowness.

Comment: Hah HAAAAAHHHHH!!!!!!
I think we have a winner... Once I turn off the 'report execution times' setting, things work a lot better.
Now, I have a situation whereby the function call method takes roughly double the time of the inline method (instead of roughly 100 times as long).
Now, this fits in with what @Twillen has been saying about Arguments.VehicleID and Local.Category each taking up space in memory. The inline method doesn't use an argument, so I'd expect it to take half as long, and indeed it does. *BUT* crucially, it's the execution time report adding the extra time.

Comment: If only I could award an answer to both of you... PeterBoughton has resolved my problem, but Twillen has answered my actual question.
You're both my heroes. ;)

Comment: **UGH!!!**
I take it all back! Disabling "Report Execution Times" in my dev environment resulted in the function method taking twice as long on the test app I posted, as opposed to 100 times as long.
However, after making that change on the live environment, the actual code in question is currently taking 10 times the amount of time as doing the lookup inline.
I'm somewhat lost now.

Comment: I’m wondering if your production server is creating a large amount of page faults. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault I've see this being the cause of slow execution times on large reports in the past, though this was on a tomcat jsp server. The solution we were able to implement was to upgrade the amount of ram the OS had for it was on a virtual hardware.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. The server in question is pretty busy with other processes, but I wouldn't know where to find information on page faults. I'm not back on there for another week or so now, but while I'm away I'm told we'll be moving to a new and much faster server, so perhaps I'll see better results then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function call will always be slower than inline code in Any language.  That's why there's `inline` keyword in C++, and in JVM land there is JIT optimizer that will inline functions for you if it deems necessary.

Now ColdFusion is yet another layer on top of JVM.  Therefore a function in CF is not a function in JVM, so things don't translate 1:1 at the JIT optimizer standpoint.  A CFML function is actually compiled down to a Java class.  Also, scopes like `arguments`, `local` (Java hashtables) are created on every invocation.  Those takes time and memory and therefore overhead.

> ...if I instantiate it in a persistent scope like Application or
>   Session, then it would be placed into memory and subsequent calls to
>   functions within that component would be lightning fast

It'd be faster than instantiating a new instance for sure, but it's not going to be "lightning fast" especially when you call it in a tight loop.

In conclusion, inline the function and if it's still not fast enough, locate the slowest part of the code and write it in Java.

Comment: While this doesn't explain why my production server is seeing much slower requests with the function call, it _does_ answer the question... much to my dismay!
I've always moved in the direction of breaking complex inline code down into smaller and smaller functions, for reasons of encapsulation, re-usability and _clean code_, so this is a harsh reality to have to deal with!

Comment: Did your production server have type checking on?  That used to slow things down quite a bit on the older versions.  To squeeze out more performance, maybe you can try enabling trusted cache.

Comment: It does have type checking on, yes - however it's CF10, so if it only hurt older versions that wouldn't apply. I'll give it a go when I'm back at the server though. Can't hurt to try.

Comment: and check & disable Server Monitoring

Comment: This is the harsh reality, that methods are slower, even well structured code might be much slower which has a definite impact when it comes to high volume.

Answer (score 0):

Just a side note here, since Railo uses inner classes instead of complete independent classes, it is  faster if you write in such a style as to have many small functions. In my experiments, both engines perform similarly with basic inline code. Adobe ColdFusion lends itself to large god functions if you need to squeak out performance under load. With the JVM being unable to inline ColdFusion functions during compilation, you'll never get the benefit of the compiler being smart with your code.

This is especially important if you created an application that uses a ton of explicit getters/setters and you find your traffic increasing from small volume to high volume. All those little functions will bring you to your knees vs. having fewer large "god" functions.

Slowest to fastest with one basic test we ran of 100,000 iterations:

Adobe ColdFusion (many small functions) ( 200X slower than Java)
Railo (many small functions) (60X slower)
ColdFusion / Railo (all code inline in one giant function) (10X slower)
Native Java Class (fastest)